# Extension on a collection type in Swift to find all the objects after an object

Tags: swift, generics, collections, functional-programming

I'd like to write an extension on CollectionType in Swift that will find the x objects after an object in an array. Obviously it needs be protected to work even if there are no objects after the item.

In my head the signatures something like this:

```
func itemsAfterItem(item: T, limit: Int?) -> [T]
```

I can't figure out how to implement it though, could someone help?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far apart from the signature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible implementation for arbitrary collections of
`Equatable` elements (explanations inline). The main
challenge is to get the parameter types and constraints right.

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element: Equatable,
                         SubSequence.Generator.Element == Generator.Element {

    func itemsAfterItem(item: Generator.Element, limit: Index.Distance?) -> [Generator.Element] {
        if let idx = indexOf(item) where idx != endIndex {
            // Start after the given item:
            let from = idx.advancedBy(1)
            // Up to min(from + limit, endIndex):
            let to = limit.map { from.advancedBy($0, limit: endIndex) } ?? endIndex
            // Return slice as an array:
            return Array(self[from..<to])
        } else {
            // Item not found, or only at the last position.
            return []
        }
    }
}
```

Understanding the

```
 let to = limit.map { from.advancedBy($0, limit: endIndex) } ?? endIndex
```

part is left as an exercise to the reader :)

Examples:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].itemsAfterItem(2, limit: 2)    // [3, 4]
["x", "y", "z"].itemsAfterItem("y", limit: 4)     // ["z"]
[1, 2, 3].itemsAfterItem(7, limit: 4)             // []
[1.1, 2.2, 3.3].itemsAfterItem(1.1, limit: nil)   // [2.2, 3.3]
```

Example for a non-array collection:

```
"abcdef".characters.itemsAfterItem("b", limit: 2) // ["c", "d"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just because I liked the challenge ;)

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable {
    func itemsAfterItem(item: Element, limit: Int? = nil) -> [Element] {
        if let from = self.indexOf(item) where from < self.count - 1 {
            if let limit = limit where from + limit < self.count {
                return Array(self[from+1...from + limit])
            }
            return Array(self[from+1...self.count-1])
        } else {
            return []
        }
    }
}
```

For the input

```
let arr = [1, 2, 4, 6, 9]
```

It results in

```
arr.itemsAfterItem(2)             // [4, 6, 9]
arr.itemsAfterItem(2, limit: 2)   // [4, 6]
arr.itemsAfterItem(2, limit: 100) // [4, 6, 9]
arr.itemsAfterItem(9, limit: 2)   // []
arr.itemsAfterItem(3, limit: 100) // []
```

Comment: I think we essentially had the same idea :) – Note that `Equatable` is sufficient, and you can simplify to `let index = self.indexOf(item)`.

Comment: @MartinR thanks! Your solution looks a bit cleaner... my swift is a litte rusty, wasn't able to program a lot due all the regular work and all pokemon go related stuff :P

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
func itemsAfterItem(item: T, limit: Int?) -> [T] {
    var counter: Int = 0
    var isAfter: Bool = false
    let array = [T]()
    let newLimit = limit != nil ? limit : myArray.count
    for tmpItem in myArray {
        if tmpItem == T {
            isAfter = true
        }
        if isAfter && counter < limit {
            array.append(tmpItem)
            counter += 1
        }
    }
}
```

> This function will put your `T` item at the start of the array.

**I've not test this function**